# [c++]Missing of destructor

Tags: c++

when I declare a new queue object like that, the exe stop working：

```
arrayQueue myQueue;  
myQueue.enqueue("111");  
char* x=myQueue.dequeue();  
cout<<x<<endl;
```

when I create the object using new, it works：

```
arrayQueue* myQueue=new arrayQueue();  
myQueue->enqueue("111");  
char* x=myQueue->dequeue();  
cout<<x<<endl;
```

so what's the problem?  the following code is a "queue" I wrote:

in .h head file：

```
class arrayQueue{  
private:  
    array<char*,100> queueContrainer;  
    int maxSize;  
    int head;  
    int tail;  
public:  
    arrayQueue();  
    ~arrayQueue();  
    bool isEmpty();  
    bool isFull();  
    int getSize();  
    void enqueue(char*);  
    char* dequeue();  
};
```

implementation in .cpp（only upload the constructor here：

```
arrayQueue::arrayQueue(){  
    head=0;  
    tail=0;  
    maxSize=100;  
    for(array<char*,100>::iterator it1=queueContrainer.begin();it1!=queueContrainer.end();++it1){  
        *it1="Empty";  
    }  
}
```

main.cpp; arrayQueue.cpp; arrayQueue.h. three files to compile:

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5FCKG1I8ce0R1RORUFYWFhUN0E/edit?usp=sharing
>   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5FCKG1I8ce0QlBCTzdBUlJfZG8/edit?usp=sharing
>   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5FCKG1I8ce0SGdWOVg1RzNTNW8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: come up with a *minimal*, compilable example.

Comment: In addition to the need for a [minimal example](http://sscce.org/), please explain what "the exe stop working" means. Does it crash? Fail to compile? Give unexpected incorrect output?

Comment: Your new type is `arrayQueue` but you're declaring an object of type `queue` as `queue myQueue;` shouldn't it be `arrayQueue myQueue;`?

Comment: yeah, that is also arrayQueue. just tape faut.

Comment: I upload already the three files compilable.

Comment: I know it's a basic question, but anyone can tell me why "arrayQueue myQueue;" doesn't work?

Comment: Looks like C++11, since there is the `array<>` type.

Comment: Since you are a "noob", please use `std::string` and not `char *`.  You really don't want to get into the troubles of pushing pointers into a queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a valid destructor? In the second example the object pointed to by `myQueue` is not deleted as it should, and the destructor never gets called.

In the first example `myQueue` is deleted when it goes out of scope, and the destructor will be called automatically. If your destructour is missing or buggy, the program will fail to compile or run.

Comment: ok. you are right! problem is solved after I add an empty destructor. thx guy!

Comment: last question, if I didn't use any "new" in my constructor. then, I can't use delete in destructor to clean the space. in that case, if I creat the object using "new", how can I delete this instance by my destructor?

Answer (score 0):

In the first line

```
queue myQueue;
```

You are creating an object of type 'queue', possibly std::queue which has no 'enqueue' or 'dequeue' methods.

Comment: `std::queue` is a template, not a class. You cannot create an object of that type, since it's not a type.

Comment: oh, sorry, in the first line should also be my class arrayQueue, not queue.